# \DeclareNewTOC called twice leads to TeX capacity exceeded - why?

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

Given this code which calls \DeclareNewTOC twice yields a TeX capacity exceeded. Removing either the first **or** the second one lets the code compile. Any idea what goes wrong?

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\DeclareNewTOC[
  category=float,
  counterwithin=none,
  float,
  floatpos=ht,
  nonfloat,
  listname={Some List Name A},
  name=TM,
  tocentrystyle=tocline,
  tocentrylevel:=table,
  tocentryindent:=table,
  tocentrynumwidth:=table,
  type=TMF,
]{ltm}

\DeclareNewTOC[
  category=float,
  counterwithin=none,
  float,
  floatpos=ht,
  nonfloat,
  listname={Some List Name B},
  name=TSR,
  tocentrystyle=tocline,
  tocentrylevel:=table,
  tocentryindent:=table,
  tocentrynumwidth:=table,
  type=TSRF,
]{tsr}


\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: comment out the second counterwith=none (I'll have to check the koma doc I have no idea currentlly if that is a package bug or user error)

Comment: I do not see `none` listed as a valid value for the `counterwithin` key so this seems to be user error.  (table 21.1 in the KOMA-script manual)

Comment: I wonder if the combination of options `category=float, float, nonfloat` makes sense...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of the `counterwithin` key has to be a declared counter name. referencing the undefined counter `none` causes an unexpandable token to be generated due to low level behaviour of the `\csname` primitive, and this causes a loop on the second use of this value. Simply remove the `counterwithin` setting in both cases.

Comment: Let me take the opportunity to give you a big "Thank You" for all of your effort. I owe you so much.